# Hexagonal Tessellation output a Triangle?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.4

Just wondering if anyone out there in the ArcMap world may know why our hexagonal tessellation outputs are coming out as Triangles and other shapes. I've attached a photo of our outputs.

We're creating a recursive search grid that digs down through data points so there's only 50 points per hex. Runs fine except when we get to levels 10 and beyond in the loop - it starts spitting out the wrong shape.

We've tried adjusting the XY Tolerance and Resolution but still no luck, hoping to see if other may have some insight. Using ArcMap 10.4 and Arcpy 2.7

[image: Tessellation Outputs]

```
import arcpy as ap
import os

ap.env.overwriteOutput = True
ap.env.workspace = "D:\\Ed_Stuff\\Testing\\All_Test_Workspace.gdb"
ap.env.XYTolerance =  "0.0000001 Meters"
ap.env.XYResolution = "0.00000001 Meters"
out_gdb ="D:\\Ed_Stuff\\Testing\\Hex_Test_Out.gdb"
pnts = "D:\\Ed_Stuff\\Hexagon.gdb\\hexagon_subset"
fc_ext = "D:\\Ed_Stuff\\Hexagon.gdb\\hexagon_subset"
final_grid = "D:\\Ed_Stuff\\Testing\\All_Test_Workspace.gdb\\Total_Tess"
a = 2560608986

def create_hex(fc_ext, final_grid, level=0, area=a):
    #pull extent from initial point feature
    desc = ap.Describe(fc_ext)
    Ext = desc.extent
    SR = desc.SpatialReference
    #create tessellation output and generation the tessellation
    out_fc = os.path.join(out_gdb, 'hex_level_{0}'.format(level))
    ap.GenerateTessellation_management(out_fc, Ext, "HEXAGON", "{0} SquareMeters".format(area), SR)
    print Ext,"____",area,"____",SR
    #make feature layer for tessellation for deletion
    ap.MakeFeatureLayer_management(out_fc, "out_fc_lyr")
    fc_join = os.path.join(out_gdb, 'join_level_{0}'.format(level))
    #spatially join the tessellation with the pnts 
    ap.SpatialJoin_analysis(out_fc, pnts, fc_join, "JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE", "KEEP_ALL", "INTERSECT")
    print fc_join
    #make a featurelayer to select and delete proper hexs from the tessellation
    ap.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc_join, "fc_join_lyr", '"Join_Count" < 50')
    ap.SelectLayerByLocation_management("out_fc_lyr", "ARE_IDENTICAL_TO", "fc_join_lyr", "", "NEW_SELECTION", "INVERT")
    ap.DeleteFeatures_management("out_fc_lyr")
    #copy the tessellation features selected to a new feature
    Holey_Tess = os.path.join(out_gdb, 'Holey_Tess_{0}'.format(level))
    ap.CopyFeatures_management("out_fc_lyr", Holey_Tess)
    print Holey_Tess

    if ap.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc_join, "fc_join_lyr_large", '"Join_Count" >= 50'):
        print "I worked!"
        large_fc = os.path.join(out_gdb, 'Large_Level_{0}'.format(level))
        ap.CopyFeatures_management("fc_join_lyr_large",large_fc)
        print "Copied"+large_fc
        results = ap.GetCount_management(large_fc)
        hexs =int(results.getOutput(0))
        print hexs
        if hexs > 0 and level < 18:
            ap.env.overwriteOutput = True
            dis_hex = os.path.join(out_gdb,'dis_hex_{0}'.format(level))
            ap.Dissolve_management(large_fc, dis_hex, '', '', "MULTI_PART", '')
            hex_multi = os.path.join(out_gdb, 'multihex_level_{0}'.format(level))
            ap.MultipartToSinglepart_management (dis_hex, hex_multi)
            print "Working... Maybe"
            with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(hex_multi, ("OBJECTID", "SHAPE@")) as cursor:
                for row in cursor:
                    print "Row: {0}".format(row[0])
                    ap.MakeFeatureLayer_management(hex_multi, 'hex_multi_lyr')
                    #ap.SelectLayerByAttribute_management('hex_multi_lyr', "NEW_SELECTION", [OBJECTID]= '')
                    hex_single = os.path.join(out_gdb, 'hex_single_{0}_{1}'.format(level, row[0]))
                    ap.CopyFeatures_management(row[1], hex_single)
                    #ap.management.Delete('hex_multi_lyr')
                    desc = ap.Describe(hex_single)
                    Ext = desc.extent
                    print Ext
                    #append the holey grid to the Total_Tess blank shp
                    ap.Append_management(hex_single, final_grid, "NO_TEST", "Join")
                    print "Appended Again"
                    create_hex(hex_single, final_grid, level+1, int(area/3))
                    print "Boots and Pants"
        elif hexs == 0 or level < 18:
            ap.Append_management('fc_join_lyr_large', final_grid, "NO_TEST", "join")
            print "Done!"


create_hex(pnts, final_grid)
```

Comment: How are you generating your tessellation?  Can you show a screenshot of the tool with your parameters (open in geoprocessing history will have it all set from the previous attempt)

Comment: What version of ArcGIS Desktop?

Comment: Using ArcGIS 10.4. And I'll screen shot the scrip and upload. It was easier to make it an Arcpy script than a model. The model got too complex.

Comment: If it's a script, please [edit] your question and add the code as *text* not as an image.  You can format the code using the **`{}`** Code Sample button on the edit toolbar to make it display correctly.

Comment: Added. Am I missing anything else?

Comment: This is a Spatial Reference issue. Setting environment preferences is meaningless when you specify an explicit SR. Please edit the question to specify what coordinate system you are using, the origin and units of the existing spatial reference, and the diagonal length at the 10th/11th level. I seriously question the wisdom of constructing hexagons the size of mitochondria.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Vince's comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/233291/hexagonal-tessellation-output-a-triangle#comment363202_233291) we were able to figure out the answer.

It seems there's a limit as to how small the hexagons can go, waiting to hear back from Esri on this.

We simply changed our R from 100000m to 50000m and increased our rate of shrink to /5 instead of /3.

If Esri gets back to us, I'll post their response here as well.